# Drupal 7 ckeditor relative path setup issue

Tags: input-formats

We are developing a site using drupal 7
So we created drupal site with name of myapp, so the url is http://localhost/myapp

Also another developer is working for same site in his development machine with the name of myapp2
so its http://localhost/myapp2

I have installed ckeditor for rich content and configured relative path for inserting images.

When I insert an image in myapp site the relative path comes like 'myapp/sites/all/files/images/img1.jpg' instead of 'sites/all/files/images/img1.jpg'

hense when I share my database with my other team member uses myapp2 they are not able view the inserted images. their path looks like this 'myapp2/myapp/sites/all/files/images/img1.jpg'

I have used pathologic to setup the two users urls in Text Format setting page
like http://localhost/myapp and http//localhost/myapp2 but not works as expected.

any one help me what else I can do to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried the solution found by searching various sites.

I put these two path items into text formats setting

```
http://localhost/myapp/
/myapp/
/
```

now its working. :)

So, since the other user who have myapp2 in his development system, there would chances for forming images path like myapp2/sites/..., hence we have to add more filter items like below

```
http://localhost/myapp2/
/myapp2/
/
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) will solve your problem, in the configuration of the filter put both http://localhost/myapp & http://localhost/myapp2 and the filter should work everything out